# Simulate normal data for different covariates with specified means and variances

Tags: r, simulation, predictor

I'd like to simulate, say 1000 cases, normal data (from normal distribution). For only one covariate (e.g., gender), the male group is from N(0,sd=1) and the female group is from N(1,sd=2), I can firstly generate the index of gender: `rbinom(n=people,size=1,prob=0.5)`. Then, I generate two sets of normal data by, for example, `rnorm(n=501,mean=0,sd=1)` and `rnorm(n=499,mean=1,sd=2)`. The resulting normal data is just combining the two-group data.

If now I have an additional covariate, school variable. Assume the school is also a binomial variable. I also want to control the means and variances of the two levels of the school variable, for example: N(0.5,sd=1) and N(1.4,sd=2), conditional on the above gender setting.

1. My quesiton is how can I achieve the two conditions simultaneously?
2. Can we extend conditions more than two covariates?

Comment: Grouping two normal samples with different parameters results in a mixture sample, not a normal sample.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to use the right name. They are treated as multiple groups in my cases.

Comment: The program multivar might do that. Follow the link on this page http://www.hermanaguinis.com/mmr/download.html

Comment: @JoelW. Thank you. I cannot run the program on my Win 10, not compatible in any modes. Sad.

Comment: Once both covariates are simulated `S=1+(runif(N)<.5)` and `G=1+(runif(N)<.5)`, the normal variate can be simulated as `X=rnrorm(N,mean=mu[S,G],sd=sigma[S,G])`

Answer (score 0):

Let Y be the outcome variable, G the gender variable, and S the school variable with levels 0 and 1. The problem amounts to specifying the dependence structure of S on Y and G such that your conditions are satisfied. That is, for each value of Y and G one needs to specify what the probability is that S takes value 1 (instead of 0), and one needs to do that in such a way that the resulting distribution of S satisfies $Y|S=0 \sim N(0.5, sd=1)$ and $Y|S=1 \sim N(1.4, sd=2)$.

There is a lot of freedom in how to do this, so I suspect there is no easy to specify general procedure.

One way to go would be to specify a parametric model for the dependence structure and then find the parameter values that result in the values of the mean and standard deviation of $Y|S=1$ and $Y|S=0$ that are closest to the ones you want. For example you could assume that gender plays no separate role and that below a certain threshold of $Y$, say $y_{low}$, one has that $P(S=0|Y) = 1$ and above a certain threshold $y_{high}$ one has that $P(S=1|Y) = 1$, while $P(S=1|Y)$ increases linearly between $y_{low}$ and $y_{high}$. You could then find the parameters $y_{low}$ and $y_{hight}$ that bring you closest to your specified values for the means and standard deviations. The more flexible the dependence model you specify is, the closer you will be able to get. One way to make the model more flexible is too allow the different genders to have different thresholds (this is the four parameter model in the code below).

In R this could be implemented like this:

```
library("stats")

simulatedata <- function(dpar, ygpar, n) {
  
  # parse arguments
  ylow = dpar[1]
  yhigh = dpar[2]
  ylowdiffG1 = dpar[3]
  yhighdiffG1 = dpar[4]
  
  mu_yg0 = ygpar[1]
  sd_yg0 = ygpar[2]
  mu_yg1 = ygpar[3]
  sd_yg1 = ygpar[4]
  
  # simulate Y
  Y = rep(NA, n)
  G = rbinom(n=n,size=1,prob=0.5)
  Y[G==0] = rnorm(n=sum(G==0),mean=mu_yg0,sd=sd_yg0)
  Y[G==1] = rnorm(n=sum(G==1),mean=mu_yg1,sd=sd_yg1)
  
  # simulate values of S outside the cutoffs
  S = rep(NA, n)
  S[Y < ylow + G * ylowdiffG1] = 0
  S[Y > yhigh + G * yhighdiffG1] = 1
  
  # simulate values of S inside the cutoffs
  for (i in 1:n) {
    if (is.na(S[i])) {
      p = max(0, min(1, (Y[i] - (ylow + G[i] * ylowdiffG1))/
                       (yhigh + G[i] * yhighdiffG1 - 
                          (ylow + G[i] * ylowdiffG1))))
      S[i] = rbinom(n=1,size=1,prob=p)
    }
  }
  
  list(Y=Y, G=G, S=S)
  
}


objective <- function(dpar, ygpar, yspar, n) {
  
  mu_ys0_t = yspar[1]
  sd_ys0_t = yspar[2]
  mu_ys1_t = yspar[3]
  sd_ys1_t = yspar[4]  
  
  d = simulatedata(dpar, ygpar, n)
  
  Y = d$Y
  G = d$G
  S = d$S
  
  # compute moments
  mu_ys0 = mean(Y[S==0])
  sd_ys0 = sd(Y[S==0])
  
  mu_ys1 = mean(Y[S==1])
  sd_ys1 = sd(Y[S==1])
  
  # compute squared loss ("distance")
  loss = (mu_ys0 - mu_ys0_t)^2 + (mu_ys1 - mu_ys1_t)^2 + 
         (sd_ys0 - sd_ys0_t)^2 + (sd_ys1 - sd_ys1_t)^2
  
  c(loss, mu_ys0, sd_ys0, mu_ys1, sd_ys1)

}


gridsearch <- function(dpars, ygpar, yspar, n) {
  
  ylows = dpars[[1]]
  yhighs = dpars[[2]]
  ylowdiffG1s = dpars[[3]]
  yhighdiffG1s = dpars[[4]]
  
  dfnrows = length(ylows)*length(yhighs)*length(ylowdiffG1s)*length(yhighdiffG1s)
  
  df = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 9, nrow = dfnrows))
  colnames(df) = c("ylow", "yhigh", "ylowdiffG1", "yhighdiffG1", "loss", 
                   "mu_ys0", "sd_ys0", "mu_ys1", "sd_ys1")
  
  pos = 1
  for (i in 1:length(ylows)) {
    for (j in 1:length(yhighs)) {
      for (k in 1:length(ylowdiffG1s)) {
        for (l in 1:length(yhighdiffG1s)) {
          df[pos, 1] = ylows[i]
          df[pos, 2] = yhighs[j]
          df[pos, 3] = ylowdiffG1s[k]
          df[pos, 4] = yhighdiffG1s[l]
          dpar = c(ylows[i], yhighs[j], ylowdiffG1s[k], yhighdiffG1s[l])
          fit = objective(dpar, ygpar, yspar, n = n)
          df[pos, 5] = fit[1]
          df[pos, 6:ncol(df)] = fit[2:length(fit)]
          pos = pos + 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  df
  
}


# given moments
mu_yg0 = 0
sd_yg0 = 1
mu_yg1 = 1
sd_yg1 = 2
ygpar = c(mu_yg0, sd_yg0, mu_yg1, sd_yg1)

# target moments
mu_ys0_t = 0.5
sd_ys0_t = 1
mu_ys1_t = 1.4
sd_ys1_t = 2
yspar = c(mu_ys0_t, sd_ys0_t, mu_ys1_t, sd_ys1_t)


## Dependency model with two parameters

nfit = 50000
nsim = 1000

# parameter values to perform gridsearch over
ylows = seq(-20, 10, 2)
yhighs = seq(10, 20, 2)
ylowdiffG1s = 0
yhighdiffG1s = 0
dpars = list(ylows, yhighs, ylowdiffG1s, yhighdiffG1s)

# find best parameters
df = gridsearch(dpars, ygpar, yspar, n=nfit)
df[which.min(df[, "loss"]), ]

# simulate data using best parameters
sim = simulatedata(unlist(df[which.min(df[, "loss"]), 1:4]), ygpar, n=nsim)
mean(sim$Y[sim$S == 0])
sd(sim$Y[sim$S == 0])
mean(sim$Y[sim$S == 1])
sd(sim$Y[sim$S == 1])


## Dependency model with four parameters

nfit = 50000
nsim = 1000

# parameter values to perform gridsearch over
ylows = seq(-2, 10, 2)
yhighs = seq(10, 16, 2)
ylowdiffG1s = seq(-22, -12, 2)
yhighdiffG1s = seq(-8, 4, 2)
dpars = list(ylows, yhighs, ylowdiffG1s, yhighdiffG1s)

# find best parameters
df = gridsearch(dpars, ygpar, yspar, n=nfit)
df[which.min(df[, "loss"]), ]

# simulate data using best parameters
sim = simulatedata(unlist(df[which.min(df[, "loss"]), 1:4]), ygpar, n=nsim)
mean(sim$Y[sim$S == 0])
sd(sim$Y[sim$S == 0])
mean(sim$Y[sim$S == 1])
sd(sim$Y[sim$S == 1])
```

A few notes:

- The dependency model is just an example and doesn't necessarily make sense. There are infinite possibilities. You can change the dependency model for S given Y and G to something more sensible for your data. `dpar` would then contain different parameters. In principle it is also possible to add further covariates and conditions here.
- `nfit` should be as large as your computer can handle to reduce random variation when searching for the best fitting parameters.
- The code performs a rough brue-force gridsearch to find the optimal parameters since the objective doesn't seem very nicely behaved, but one could also try more sophisticated optimization methods using `optim`.
- For the two-parameter model the best cutoff values are around $-2$ and $14$, with a loss of $0.5$ and resulting moments of $\mu_{Y|S=0} ≈ 0.3$, $sd_{Y|S=0} ≈ 1.6$, $\mu_{Y|S=1} ≈ 1.5$, and $sd_{Y|S=1} ≈ 1.7$.
- For the four-parameter model the best cutoff values are around $2$ and $12$ for $G=0$ and around $2-14=-12$ and $12-2=10$ for $G=1$, with a loss of $0.2$ and resulting moments of $\mu_{Y|S=0} ≈ 0.2$, $sd_{Y|S=0} ≈ 1.4$, $\mu_{Y|S=1} ≈ 1.3$, and $sd_{Y|S=1} ≈ 2.0$.
- A different dependency model might result in a better fit. However, in general it can be the case that the specified conditions cannot be satisfied exactly.

Comment: I'm not sure my understanding is correct, but it seems the distributino of the two levels of gender is omitted(?) Could you clarify how to carry out it in R?

Comment: If I read you correctly then the distribution of the two levels of gender (below denoted 0 and 1) would be $Y|G=0 \sim N(0, sd=1)$ and $Y|G=1 \sim N(1, sd=2)$. Together with the distribution of G they determine the distribution of Y, hence the distribution of the levels is included through Y.

Comment: Also added some more description on how you could proceed.